# Use WordPress simply as post database to feed your own custom site

Tags: wordpress

I have built my website using HTML, CSS and PHP and have built a blog homepage and an article page.

I want to use WordPress to write these posts. I want my own code to be able to query these posts and get title, date, image and content and input these into my own `<h2>`, `<img>`, `<p>` etc.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Wordpress Rest API https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/.

Then in your website, add the following html and JavaScript:

HTML

```
<div id="my-posts"></div>
```

JavaScript (Be sure to add your website url, with protocol)

```
fetch('YOUR_WEBSITE/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
 .then(function(json) {    
    json.forEach(function(post, index) {
      var para = document.createElement("P");                       
      var t = document.createTextNode(post.title.rendered);     
      para.appendChild(t);                                          
      document.getElementById("my-posts").appendChild(para);         
    })
  });
```

The code above will request the posts and render their titles inside of div#my-posts. The JavaScript will need to execute after the HTML.

Look at the handbook to see how you can get the data you need from the API.

Good luck, and happy coding!